# How to loop array of JSON object using SwiftyJSON?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to loop an array of JSON objects but it keeps giving me error

```
[
  {
    "key" : "501",
    "latitude" : 3.0691697,
    "longitude" : 333.64444639369011,
    "distance" : 5,
  },
  {
    "key" : "502",
    "latitude" : 3.073096722364426,
    "longitude" :12.4444000,
    "distance" : 487,
  }
]
```

The code example

```
if let value = response.result.value {
   let json = JSON(value)

  // This is the part Where I got stuck                  
   for item in json {

       print (item["latitude"]) // Keep giving me "Latitude is not a subscript of JSON"
    }
}
```

If I `print item` to see the value, I will get

```
("0", {
  "latitude" : 3.0691697,
  "longitude" : 333.64444639369011,
  "key" : "501",
  "distance" : 5
})
("1", {
  "latitude" : 3.073096722364426,
  "longitude" : 12.4444000,
  "key" : "502",
  "distance" : 487
})
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: `let json = JSON(value)`  to   `let json = JSON(value) as! [String:AnyObject]` And try

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#loop) for looping through `json` with `SwiftyJson`.

Comment: @MikeAlter crash the entire app.

Answer (score 2):

Your `keys` are of type `String`. Here your keys are `"0"`, `"1"` etc.

Try this:

```
for (index,subJson):(String, JSON) in json {
    //Do something you want
    print (subJson["latitude"])
}
```

**Edit:** If you don't want to use `index` for anything, you can just replace `index` using a `_` like:

```
for(_, subJson): (String, JSON) in json {
        print(subJson["latitude"])
}
```

Comment: I tried to convert JSON to CLLocationDegrees and it is not possible.

Comment: Well, this is not related to ___How to loop array of JSON object using SwiftyJSON?___ question. And what do you mean by "it is not possible"?

Answer (score 0):

try this piece of code

```
for (key0,json) in response.result.value as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject> 
{
    print("key0 \(key0), json \(json)")
    for (key,val) in json as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
    {
        print("key \(key), val \(val)")
    }
}
```